# Использование строки документации __doc__

Tags: python

какие преимущества имеет строка документаций `__doc__`

Comment: Преимущества перед чем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Преимущество: наличие документации. Недостаток: документацию нужно писать.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет ни преимуществ, ни недостатков. Это встроенный функционал. Выбирать использовать или нет предстоит вам или вашему руководителю. По факту у каждого объекта существует атрибут `__doc__`. Она может быть либо `None`, либо строковым литералом.

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> a.__doc__
"int([x]) -> integer\nint(x, base=10) -> integer\n\nConvert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments\nare given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point\nnumbers, this truncates towards zero.\n\nIf x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,\nbytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the\ngiven base.  The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded\nby whitespace.  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 
2-36.\nBase 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.\n>>> int('0b100', base=0)\n4"
>>> type.__doc__   
"type(object_or_name, bases, dict)\ntype(object) -> the object's type\ntype(name, bases, dict) -> a new type"
# а вот тип данных None, парадоксально, но docstring не имеет, то есть имеет значение None
>>> None.__doc__
>>>
```

Строковой литерал применяется в функциях, классах и модулях. При исполнении данная строка игнорируется, но распознается компилятором и помещается в атрибут `__doc__` классов, функции и модулей. Первая строка после объявления класса, функции или модуля является каноническим. Только так `docstring` распознается.

Пример с директивой `help`, которая умеет их распозновать

```py
>>> def func(t):
...   """Test docstring""" 
... 
>>> help(func)
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(t)
    Test docstring
```

И как пример, не верное использование

```py
>>> def func(t):
...   t += 5
...   """Not canon, this is not a docstring"""     
... 
>>> help(func)
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(t)
```